# How to kill background audio from view that was already dismissed

Tags: swift, swiftui, avaudioplayer

The main view of my app is a list of songs.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (fileURLs, id: \.path) { song in
                NavigationLink(destination: PlayView(songURL: song)) {
                    SongRow(songURL: song)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Songs"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
        }

    }

}
```

You tap on a song and it navigates to a PlayView, which instantiates an audio player:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct PlayView: View {

    var songURL: URL

    @State var player : AVAudioPlayer!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                self.playPause()
            }) {
                Text("Play/Pause")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            self.player = try! AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: self.songURL)
            self.playPause()
        }
    }

    func playPause() {
        if self.player.isPlaying {
            self.player.pause()
        } else {
            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is when I navigate to another song's PlayView, it plays the audio **on top of** the first song (i.e. both play simultaneously). How should I kill the first song when the second song plays?

Comment: What about calling `self.player.stop()` to 'stop' the audio?

Comment: @fuzz do you mean, that you can have only one instance of ```AVAudioPlayer``` for all the application and can't create 2 or more (as I see here)? I think author creates a lot of instances of audio player, but controlling only last of them. If this is not true, I can rewrite my solution at the project and delete my answer :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my project I'm using only one instance of `final class` everywhere in the app. I think the problem in you case is that you're creating lots of instances of `AVPlayer` in children views (`PlayView`) but can control only one of them. Here is example of my solution:

```swift
import AVKit
import Combine

final class AudioPlayer: AVPlayer, ObservableObject {

    @Published var currentPlaylist: [Song]? = nil
    @Published var currentSong: Song? = nil
    // ...
    // MARK: player controls
    func playPausePlayer(withSong song: Song, forPlaylist playlist: [Song]? = nil) {

        setCurrentPlaylist(newPlaylist: playlist, newSong: song)
        if currentSong == song {
            continueOrPauseCurrentSong()
        } else {
            changeSong(with: song)
        }

        self.controlPanel?.updateNowPlaying()

    }
    // simplified func (I leave only what you need)
     private func changeSong(with newSong: Song) {

        if let url = URL.init(string: newSong.url) {

            let nextPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem.init(url: url)
            self.replaceCurrentItem(with: nextPlayerItem) // here you change the song
            self.play()

            currentSong = newSong
        } else {...}
    }
    // ...
}
```

where `Song` is just a struct with song data, like:

```swift
struct Song: Codable, Equatable, Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id: String
    let url: String
    // and so on
}
```

At the `SceneDelegate` func I set this AudioPlayer as an `environmentObject` for using it in HomeView() and all it's children views. So you can play/pause your player or change the song (with `.replaceCurrentItem(with: ...` method) from everywhere. In your case it should be something like this:

```swift
class SceneDelegate: UIResponder, UIWindowSceneDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {
    // ...
    let homeView = ContentView()
            .environment(\.managedObjectContext, context)
            .environmentObject(AudioPlayer()) // here I set only one player for main window, so all the children will use it too

        // Use a UIHostingController as window root view controller.
        if let windowScene = scene as? UIWindowScene {
            let window = UIWindow(windowScene: windowScene)
            window.rootViewController = UIHostingController(rootView: homeView)
            self.window = window
            window.makeKeyAndVisible()
        }
    }
}

// Based on your code snippet:
struct ContentView: View {

        @EnvironmentObject var player: AudioPlayer // add this for main view
        var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List (fileURLs, id: \.path) { song in
                NavigationLink(destination: PlayView(songURL: song)) {
                    SongRow(songURL: song)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            .navigationBarTitle(Text("Songs"))
                .navigationBarItems(trailing: addButton)
        }

    }

}

struct PlayView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var player: AudioPlayer // and for child view (they all will have one object
    var songURL: URL

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button(action: {
                 self.playPause()
            }) {
                Text("Play/Pause")
            }
        }.onAppear {
            // set or change currentItem of player
        }
    }

    func playPause() {
        if self.player.isPlaying {
            self.player.pause()
        } else {
            self.player.play()
        }
    }
}
```

**P.S.** if I am wrong with the assumption that several instances of `AVPlayer` may exist please tell me in comments